# Send data from one website to another on browser level

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I need to send data amount (not more then 5000 symbols) from one website to another on browser level. How can I do it?

I can put any PHP code on the first server, but data processing should be not on server level (not SOAP, curl, etc) because of performance and stability reason (pages need to be loaded fastly, data transfer should be done only after load).

So, on first server I have data, which I need to send 'on fly', on second I have PHP server that catch it. It is not necessary to catch response from server.

As I know, AJAX can be done only on the same domain.

One method I know is to create  tag with src = some file on second server. Like www.test.com/myimage.png?param="testtsttest". But GET has limitation.

Comment: you can do it using AJAX (CORS and XMLHttpRequest level 2)

Comment: What browsers have CORS support? Do IE7 has it?

Comment: see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: Yes, I found one more good table http://enable-cors.org/client.html

Comment: Why not just do a POST? Simple and easy ;-)

Comment: I need to show content on this page and in the same time to send data to another server

Comment: Html5 websocket might also be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), which allows you to transfer JSON data between 2 servers.

Comment: As I can understand, JSONP uses usual GET to load script from external server, and GET has symbols restriction less then 5000, so I will not be able to send big data. If only I will make several JSONP requests on one page.

Comment: It seems I didn't understand the issue here then. Could you try to explain the data flow between the servers?

Comment: 1 server should send a large amount of data to another server (5000 symbols) from every page. It cann't be done on PHP level, because page load speed is critical. But it can be done in js or in some other way. In your example I can send not a big amount of data. It is better for receiving info as I can see.